# Haproxy add request unique ID to the response

Tags: haproxy, response-headers

Following HAProxy documentation I added the following to my configuration:

```
unique-id-format %{+X}o\ %ci:%cp_%fi:%fp_%Ts_%rt:%pid
unique-id-header X-Unique-ID
```

It works fine but I would also to add the X-Unique-ID to the responses.
I tried with

```
http-response set-header X-Unique-ID "%ID"
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to add the unique request ID to the response headers and if yes what is the proper way to do it?

PS: It wasn't super clear in my original question but I would like the ID added to the response to be the same than the ID generated for the request that triggered this response. This way I can more easily regroup requests and their responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [http-after-response set-header](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#4.2-http-after-response%20set-header)

```
http-after-response set-header X-Unique-ID "%ID"
```

As you have not added the output of `haproxy -vv` I assume you use the latest haproxy version

Comment: Yes, I am running the latest version.